# HashMap Object ~ myMap is created in a public Java Method

Tags: java, object, constructor, hashmap, instances

Below is my starting code. I have learned a bit on HashMaps, created them and used them. But I am having a problem creating a copy of a HashMap I have built. I can recreate a new one, but the idea is to have some Keys & values of a map built, but from another method. My methods are all public. I have created a private myMap in the Class. But when I try to access myMap in another method, the most I get is an empty {}. Occasionally I get 'null' but I figured out at least how to get from nullto to {}. I just want to be able to .getKey... to get the HashMap data.

Hope this is clear? If not will try to send more.

```
public class CodonCount {  
   private HashMap<String,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

public CodonCount() { 
System.out.println("myMap (beginning of Constructor) = " + myMap);
  }

public HashMap buildCodonMap(int start, String dna) {
 System.out.println("myMap (beginning of buildCodonMap) = " + myMap);       
HashMap<String,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already have `myMap` declared as a class variable, if you do this

```
public HashMap buildCodonMap(int start, String dna) {
  System.out.println("myMap (beginning of buildCodonMap) = " + myMap);       
  HashMap<String,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
  ....
}
```

you are re-declaring `myMap`

try

```
public HashMap buildCodonMap(int start, String dna) {
   System.out.println("myMap (beginning of buildCodonMap) = " + myMap);     
   myMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
   ....
}
```

Comment: Scary, you are brilliant. Now I don't need the myMap = new HashMap<String,Integer> because my problem was that I was trying to 'Overdo' something I have to watch myself. (i.e. If you have ever watched the sitcom "The Middle", think of me as Brick)

Comment: [REVISED] Scary, you are brilliant. Now I don't need the myMap = new HashMap<String,Integer> because my problem was that I was trying to 'Overdo' something I have to watch myself. (i.e. If you have ever watched the sitcom "The Middle", think of me as Brick)

   public void tester(){
   String key = "TCA";
   Integer value = myMap.get(key);
   System.out.println("The codon value is: " + value);
   }

output from the tester:
The codon value is: 2 

myMap (beginning of buildCodonMap) = {}
myMap (after building HashMap in buildCodonMap) = {CGT=1, TCA=2, AGT=1}

Comment: If this answer was useful please consider accepting this answer